# Overriding method of type (String, Int, Boolean) => Double has incompatible type

Tags: scala

the following code should typecheck afaik, but it doesn't. I'd rather avoid giving names to the argument types as those can change in arity and type.

```
trait Foobar[K] {
     def method: K => Double
}
class Test extends Foobar[(String, Int, Boolean)] {
     override def method: (String, Int, Boolean) => Double = (_, _, _) => 3.0
      // This also fails
     // override def method: (String, Int, Boolean) => Double = { case (_, _, _) => 3.0 }
}
```

The error is

> overriding method method in trait Foobar of type => ((String, Int, Boolean) => Double; method method has incompatible type
>   override def method: (String, Int, Boolean) => Double = (*,*,_) => 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very trivial but very tedious problem.

`(String, Int, Boolean) => Double`. is a function of three arguments to a double.
But you want a function of one argument *(a tuple of three elements)* to a double.

Try with:

```
class Test extends Foobar[(String, Int, Boolean)] {
  override def method: ((String, Int, Boolean)) => Double = {
    case (_, _, _) => 3.0
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the tuple syntax all together? I always meant "a function of three arguments" never "a function of one argument, a tuple of three" but there seems to be no other way. I'm looking for something like `String => Int => Boolean => Double`

Comment: @rausted open a new question and be very specific about what are you trying to model and show this as an example. As a quick answer, no. You can not abstract over different arities for functions, think you are the caller, how would you call it if you do not even know how many arguments doesn't it receives?

Comment: Well, you can simplify to `case _` or just `_ => 3.0`.